# Не равны или неравны

Tags: частица-не

Силы слишком не равны или неравны. «Слишком не» подходит для раздельного написания?

Comment: Нацкорпус дает 1 к 28 в пользу слитного написания. Я бы проверял так: если можно вставить "были" между не и равны, то можно писать раздельно. В вашем примере получается "Силы слишком не были равны.". Явный бред.

Answer (score 5):

Частица НЕ  при наличии усилительных слов *весьма, крайне, очень* и др. пишется слитно: ***Силы слишком неравны.***

**1. Правило**

[Розенталь: § 57. Частица *не* с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)

Пункт 6. Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает наречие меры и степени (***весьма, крайне, очень, почти*** или наречное выражение в высшей степени и т. п.), то частица *не* с прилагательным всегда пишется слитно: весьма некрасивый поступок; крайне неуместный выпад; очень неудачное выступление; почти незнакомый текст; в высшей степени неразборчивый почерк.

Пункт 9. С краткими формами прилагательных частица *не* пишется в основном так же, как с полными:

Ср. написание не с краткой формой прилагательного при наличии различных пояснительных слов: **Слишком неуверенны** были люди в будущем; Он совершенно незнаком с последними достижениями в области зоотехники; Эта река всегда неспокойна (здесь **усиление утверждения**).

Но: Никакой контроль тут уже не возможен. Они ни в чём не похожи друг на друга.  Эта река никогда не спокойна (здесь **усиление отрицания**).

**2. Примеры**

Он ловко увертывался от ударов, однако сдвинуть с места героя так и не смог. Силы были **слишком неравны.**  [Запись LiveJournal (2004)]

Но силы были **слишком неравные**. Казаки несколько раз атаковали баррикад, были отброшены и сочли за благо уступить место артиллерии. [Ю. В. Трифонов. (1965)]

**3. Из словаря**

**НЕРАВНЫЙ,**  1. Неодинаковый, несходный в каком-л. отношении. **СЛИШКОМ,** нареч. Сверх меры, чересчур; очень.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:

> Силы слишком неравны́.

Это краткое прилагательное. И после "слишком" не может быть отрицания, может только утверждаться что-то с приставкой *не-.* По-английски вот тоже нельзя сказать *very not clear,* зато можно *very unclear* или *very vague.*

Comment: Извините, Артём, мне _кажется,_ что правильно **неравны́** (http://www.endic.ru/word_stress/Neravnyj-16390.html).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Да, конечно, интуиция подвела.